# Firefox quantum(version-68.0.1) issue when upload one file then reload tab automatically and upload same file multiple time

Tags: php, file-upload, firefox-quantum

We are facing one issue when we upload a file from website. It's working fine on chrome and Firefox older(version 60.8.0) version but when we try to upload file from Firefox (version-68.0.1) then browser tab automatically reload multiple time and also same file upload multiple time. So can you please help me that how can i overcome from this issue and suggest me any idea that actually this issue is from Firefox new version or any other issue.

We have checked in Firefox old version(60.8.0) and chrome browser and it's working fine but currently i am facing issue in Firefox(v-68.0.1)

When we click file upload button then browser tab reload automatically and same file upload multiple time.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: I am facing issue on Firefox quantum(version-68.0.1) and in older versions it's working file

Comment: I think it's Firefox quantum new version issue because i am facing this issue is only newer version